# Invalid Character in ReportServer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

When I am trying to execute few reports in **ReportManager** its throwing error.

```
The attempt to connect to the report server failed.Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
There is an error in XML document(1,134206).
'',hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 134206.
```

When I execute form **report server** it executing successfully.

The same rdl file is working perfectly in other System using **ReportManager**.

What can be the issue?

And how can we produce this error in the working system? And how can we solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the field, there is some invalid character as in the image.

And report Manager is unable to process it while executing rdl file.

We got the DB backup from the client and replicated in other systems as well.
[Invalid Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF2mE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The character producing the error is 0x0C, which is a char FF, escaped as \f,
sometimes used as a page or section break.
As a first troubleshooting step you can remove this char and see if the report works.

You can find this char in your rdl if you open it with Notepad++, for instance,and search for \f (in search mode extended). You can then remove this char and rerun.

The second step is to determine why it works in one system and not in another, which could well be down to a difference in the SSRS and/or OS version of the systems in question.